# Follow TCP stream on multiple TCP sessions?

Tags: wireshark

I'm using Wireshark to sniff some HTTP traffic (Fiddler won't do because my app doesn't use a proxy).

I'd like to move from the "packet view" into views of the entire HTTP sessions - all of the sessions, not just one of them.

Is there something like "Follow TCP Stream" that isn't limited to a single TCP connection?

(Desired output is basically a series of HTTP requests / responses - I'm only interested in the text of the response)

Comment: If you don't mind a UNIX command-line tool, you could give [Bro](http://www.bro-ids.org) a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the filter 'http' to display just the http request & responses in the packet view.
2. Click on one of the response packets (HTTP 1.1 200 OK)
3. The body of the response is decoded by Wireshark at the bottom of the response packet

[image]

Comment: Yeah, but that's per packet ... I guess you can work with that, but I wonder if there's a tool that does it on a session level.

Comment: What do you mean by 'session level' for http?  Do mean tracking a session on a particular website, eg a facebook session?

Comment: a TCP session that spans multiple packets. Wireshark shows & parses the response in the single packet only in the view you suggested.

Comment: No - if you look carefully, you can see the line (beginning '4 reassembled TCP segments...) where Wireshark is telling you which packets the complete response is assembled from.

Comment: Hmm, didn't know that. It makes this a viable answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use Statistics -> Conversation List -> TCP

Answer (score 0):

Sniffing HTTP traffic on Wireshark is limited.
I would suggest you to use PF_RING of www.ntop.org

For more details,please check the website
http://www.ntop.org/products/pf_ring/

Comment: Softperfect Traffic Analizer is also good for tcp sessions. Easy to track images, files, webpages and so on.